# Can SSH into server but not git push

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am unable to push to my remote git repo stored on my Amazon ec2 instance.

My local `ssh` `config` file has a host entry that looks like this:

```
Host ec2
    HostName ec2-54-89-205-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ec2TestB
```

And so I can run the command `ssh ec2` and I will successfully connect to the `ec2`.

Next, I created a `git repo` on the `ec2` in the `root` folder called `testGitRoot`.  On my local machine I created a `git repo` called `testGitLocal`.  I then add the `ec2` `repo` with `git remote add origin ec2user@ec2-54-89-205-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/root/testGitRoot` (I've also tried it without the `ec2user@` part.. not sure if that is needed).

Bit when I run `git push origin master` I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So my question is what concepts am I missing here?  If I'm able to connect over ssh with `ssh ec2`, then why can't I push my repo?  One thing that isn't clear to me is how exactly the git setup steps I took even utilize `ssh`.  Normally, I'm always pushing to github, in which case I take the `ssh` url and set that as my remote.  In this case I'm just setting my `ec2` `repo` as remote where that url is just `ec2Domain:path/to/git/repo`. So I'm not sure even *if* the `git push origin master` is using `ssh`, and if it is, why is it seeming to fail over the public key when the `ssh ec2` command doesn't??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the repository using the user `ec2-user`, as shown in your ssh_config file:

```
Host ec2
    User ec2-user
```

But you set the remote to use a different username, `ec2user`:

```
git remote add origin ec2user@ec2 ...
```

You say ssh works, but git does not. Therefore, git is likely the one with an incorrect username.

To fix it, just change the remote URL so it has the right username:

```
git remote set-url origin \
    ec2-user@ec2-54-89-205-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/root/testGitRoot
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message means you failed to authenticate.

These are common reasons that can cause that:

- Trying to connect with the wrong key. Are you sure this instance is using this keypair?
- Trying to connect with the wrong username. `ubuntu` is the username for the Ubuntu-based AWS distribution, but on some others it's `ec2-user` (or `admin` on some Debians)
- Trying to connect the wrong host. Is that the right host you are trying to log in to?

Note that 1. will also happen if you have messed up the `/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on your EC2 instance.

About 2., the information about which username you should use is often lacking from the AMI Image description. But you can find some in AWS EC2 documentation.

Bullet point 4. : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: i'm using (i think) the CentOS AMI so I'm sure that the user is `ec2user`.  I was unsure whether the `user@` syntax was required in `git remote add origin <domain>`.  basically is it `<domain>`?  or `<user>@<domain>`?  Also I have no idea which keypair is the right one.  I've setup both git rep's and simply added the remote as origin with the domain name.  As I said in my question I'm not even sure IF its using ssh.

Comment: `git remote add origin $URL`. If you use ssh-type URL git will use ssh. See [git URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a).